# How to run es6 in cypress plugins?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

Cypress plugins run code in node 8.2.1 process which doesn't support spread operator for objects. I need to require a file that uses it. Is there a workaround to require a file which runs in node 10 environment?

Comment: May be I'm wrong, node environment should be depending on what you have installed in your machine. Based on Cypress's `package.json`, I see it supporting `"node": ">=8.2.1"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Cypress plugins file is run in the Node that's bundled alongside with Cypress's Electron app.

Youcan  work around this in two ways:

1. Auto-compile files imported into the plugins file, by using `@babel/register` plugin. Remember, this workaround won't work for the plugins file itself.

   First, install it:

   ```sh
   npm install -D @babel/register @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread
   ```

   Then, on top of your `plugins/index.js`, do (babel@7):

   ```js
   require("@babel/register")({
       plugins: [ "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread" ]
   });
   ```

   https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-register.html
2. Run the plugins file using your system's Node executable.

   Cypress allows you to set `nodeVersion` [configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Node-version), which controls this behavior.

   E.g., set in `cypress.json`:

   ```
   {
       "nodeVersion": "system"
   }
   ```

   Note: this of course works only if your system's Node already supports that feature.